# How to properly check for null character

Tags: c, list, null

Having read through some of the answers to this same question posted on the website, I've found that I apparently have made no mistakes when coding this check up. Never-the-less, I keep getting warnings so I decided to ask a question to solve this.

Here is my code, and I will explain the issue in a moment.

```
typedef struct node{
    char data;
    struct node *next;
} node;

// ...

if(head->data == '\0' || head->data == NULL)
    return NULL;
```

Assume head points to the beginning of a linked list which simulates a char*. The purpose of this if statement is to check to see if the head is NULL or if the first character is endline, upon which a print statement elsewhere in my code says "(empty string)."

Upon building my program, I receive a warning about my code. It says the following:

> warning: comparison between pointer and integer

I am having difficulty testing the case where the string becomes NULL (due to my inexperience with Windows command line) so it would be nice to know how to address these warnings before I try to tackle this problem. Any advice?

Comment: `data` is a `char`, neither an array, nor a pointer to `char`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say "Assume head points to the beginning of a linked list which simulates a `char*`. The purpose of this `if` statement is to check to see if the head is NULL or if the first character is endline."

```
if(head->data == '\0' || head->data == NULL)
    return NULL;
```

But you don't check `head`, as in your objective, you are checking the data value of the first list element twice. And you check it for two conflictings types - it can't be a char (`'\0'`) and a char pointer (`NULL`) at the same time.

You should check if the first node pointer is a *list* terminator, as well as the first `char` is a *string* terminator.

So I would amend your test to

```
if (head == NULL || head->data == '\0')
```

Answer (score 3):

`head->data` will not equal `NULL`, it's not a pointer. If you're doing C strings, then checking for the `\0` character will suffice. There isn't anything more to it.

Comment: It is a `char`, not a string (i.e. array).

Comment: That would not be a "C string" - actually not a string at all (and very inefficient, too).